# Almacenar valor minimo promedio python

Tags: python, array

Tengo el siguiente código en donde me solicitan sacar un promedio de un vector, tengo que sacar el valor mas alto y el valor mas bajo, el alto ya se como hacerlo con un contador, pero el menor se me ha complicado dado que la condición siempre se me cumple y me cambia el valor. Acá el código:

```py
suma1=0
suma2=0
numero=int(input("Cuantos datos: "))
for i in range(1,numero+1):
    dato=input("valores: ")
    listSep=dato.split()
    vector=listSep[1:8]
    identificador=listSep[0]
    #ArrayT.append(dato)
    promedio=sum(map(float,vector))/7
    ident=i
    if promedio > suma1:
        suma1=promedio
        ident1=ident
        print("Mayor",promedio)
    if promedio < suma1:
        suma2=promedio
        ident2=ident
        print("Menor",promedio)
```

El inconveniente es que tengo que sacar el promedio de unos valores que previamente almaceno en un vector pero que tengo que separar. Por ejemplo:
`dato=[1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]`
Donde el primer valor `int` es para la variable identificador, y los valores restantes tipo `float` son para la variable vector. De esa variable vector tengo que sacar el promedio

Comment: Son variables globales, ya lo edite

Comment: por que divides entre 7?

Comment: porque en los datos de entrada me pasan 8 datos, 7 dividen float y el restante es el que me sirve para el promedio

Comment: mira tu código no te imprime el menor dado que en el primer `if` a `suma1` le asignas el valor de `promedio` por lo que al hacer `if promedio < suma1` te dará `False` por que ambos tienen el mismo valor, si quieres hallar el valor máximo, puedes hacer con la función `max()` y para el minimo con `min()`

Comment: en el ejemplo que das solo estas pasando 4 datos :/

Comment: si se ejecuta tu codigo con los datos que das el resultado será `4.2857...` lo que es el resultado de dividir `(10+10+10)/7` y esto no es el promedio

Comment: Es un ejemplo estimado, tengo que pasar los 7 datos completos no los puse todos. En todo caso como indique tengo que sacar otros datos aparte del promedio como el numero de la iteracion y el identificador del dato, por ello no puedo usar las min max.
entrada
dato=[1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10]
salida
promedio 10
identificador 1
iteracion 1

Comment: con identificador te refieres a la posicion del elemento?

Comment: Exacto, ese identificador me sirve para aislar el primer elemento que me envian en el vector que es un int y precede a los 7 numeros tipo float.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126618/discussion-between-christian-and-andavid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El cálculo del promedio de un `vectorv` es:

```
def promedio(vector):
    return sum(vector) / len(vector)
```

Ahora haremos un código con un ciclo infinito. En cada ciclo pide un vector, ingresandolo como una serie de valores separados por coma.:

```
1,2.3,4.5,6.0
```

En la lista `proms` guardaremos el promedio calculado para vector ingresado.

```
proms = []
```

Este es el ciclo infinito: pedimos un vector, lo separamos en sus partes usando `split` y convertimos cada subcadena a `float`, armando finalment el vector.

```
while True:
    dato = input("Ingrese vector de datos separados por comas:").split(",")
    if len(dato) > 1:
        proms.append(promedio([float(x) for x in dato[1:]]))
        print(proms[-1])
    else:
        break
```

Luego de terminar el ingreso, podemos calcular el mayor y menor promedio:

```
if proms:
    print(f"Mayor: {max(proms)}")
    print(f"Menor: {min(proms)}")
```

**Demo**

```
def promedio(vector):
    return sum(vector) / len(vector)

proms = []
while True:
    dato = input("Ingrese vector de datos separados por comas:").split(",")
    if len(dato) > 1:
        proms.append(promedio([float(x) for x in dato[1:]]))
        print(proms[-1])
    else:
        break

if proms:
    print(f"Mayor: {max(proms)}")
    print(f"Menor: {min(proms)}")
```

produce

```
Ingrese vector de datos separados por comas:1,2.3, 4.5
3.4
Ingrese vector de datos separados por comas:10,2,3,4.5,6.7
4.05
Ingrese vector de datos separados por comas:
Mayor: 4.05
Menor: 3.4

Process finished with exit code 0
```